# Let R be the region of the disc $ x^2+y^2\leq1 $ in the first quadrant. Then the area of the largest possible circle contained in R

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, area, maxima-minima

Let R be the region of the disc $ x^2+y^2\leq1 $    in the
first quadrant. Then the area of the largest
possible circle contained in R is $\pi.(3-2\sqrt 2)$.

My Attempt :

If I draw a tangent of the circle  $ x^2+y^2=1 $at the point $(1/\sqrt 2 , 1/\sqrt 2)$. Then we will get a isosceles triangle whose sides are the tangent , X axis and Y axis . Now the circle inscribed in this triangle will be the biggest among the all circles which completely lie in the triangle. So the area of this circle will be the required area.

Can anyone please tell me if I have gone wrong anywhere?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Now that you've nailed down where the circle is, you just have to figure out its area (or radius).

Comment: But can you please explain me why incirlce cover the largest area among the  all circles contained in a triangle?@JaapScherphuis

Comment: If a circle inside a triangle does not touch any of the sides of that triangle, then it is not the largest possible. Any circle inside a triangle that touches only one or two sides can be moved so that it touches none of the sides, so is also not the largest possible. Therefore the largest possible circle touches all three sides of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy to prove this is the optimum would be as follows:

1. Assume the center of the circle lies on the line $x=y$, for each point on the line compute the area of the circle and show that your solution is the maximum
2. Assume the optimum does not lie on the line $x=y$, then shifting the center towards this line will allow a bigger radius to circle to fit into the region. Hence the point away from this line are not optimal.